# nodejs - Can't resolve 'child_process' with gRPC and webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm trying to use gRPC with javascript. I want to use the gRPC package, as I need to send some metadata, but I get an error when I'm using `require('grpc')`.

Here's the error message:
Can't resolve 'child_process'

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/detect-libc/lib/detect-libc.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/sglab/dev/grpc-web/client/node_modules/detect-libc/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/detect-libc/lib/detect-libc.js 4:16-40
 @ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js
 @ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js
 @ ./node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js
 @ ./node_modules/grpc/index.js
 @ ./client.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/detect-libc/lib/detect-libc.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sglab/dev/grpc-web/client/node_modules/detect-libc/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/detect-libc/lib/detect-libc.js 5:18-31
 @ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js
 @ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js
 @ ./node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js
 @ ./node_modules/grpc/index.js
 @ ./client.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sglab/dev/grpc-web/client/node_modules/fs.realpath'
 @ ./node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js 24:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/glob/glob.js
 @ ./node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
 @ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/napi.js
 @ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js
 @ ./node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js
 @ ./node_modules/grpc/index.js
 @ ./client.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/glob.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sglab/dev/grpc-web/client/node_modules/glob'
 @ ./node_modules/glob/glob.js 43:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
 @ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/napi.js
 @ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js
 @ ./node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js
 @ ./node_modules/grpc/index.js
 @ ./client.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/sync.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sglab/dev/grpc-web/client/node_modules/glob'
 @ ./node_modules/glob/sync.js 4:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/glob/glob.js
 @ ./node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
 @ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/napi.js
 @ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js
 @ ./node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js
 @ ./node_modules/grpc/index.js
 @ ./client.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/grpc/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sglab/dev/grpc-web/client/node_modules/grpc'
 @ ./node_modules/grpc/index.js 22:9-22
 @ ./client.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sglab/dev/grpc-web/client/node_modules/grpc/src'
 @ ./node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js 34:11-24
 @ ./node_modules/grpc/index.js
 @ ./client.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/sglab/dev/grpc-web/client/node_modules/rimraf'
 @ ./node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js 6:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/napi.js
 @ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js
 @ ./node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js
 @ ./node_modules/grpc/index.js
 @ ./client.js
```

The problems shows when I use this line: `var grpc = required('grpc')` and this command: `npx webpack <file>`.

Here's `package.json` file:

```
{
 "name": "example",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "description": "example",
 "devDependencies": {
  "@grpc/proto-loader": "^0.3.0",
  "google-protobuf": "^3.6.1",
  "grpc": "^1.24.4",
  "grpc-web": "^1.0.0",
  "webpack": "^4.16.5",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
 }
}
```

I'm not really familiar with node.js, so it would be great if someone could explain it to me.

Thanks in advance for help!